# Select not null values in dataframes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a CSV file in Spark 2.0 and counting not null values in a column using the following:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(dir)

df.filter("IncidntNum is not null").count()
```

and it works fine when I test it using spark-shell. When I create a jar file containing the code and submit it to spark-submit, I get an exception at second line above :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', ..
== SQL ==
IncidntNum is not null
^^^

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:197)
```

Any idea why this would happen when I'm using the code that works in spark-shell?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been sitting around a while, but better late than never.

The most likely reason I can think of is that when running using spark-submit you are running in "cluster" mode.  That means the driver process will be located on a different machine than when you run spark-shell.  That could cause Spark to read a different file.